# overflow property using css

Tags: html, css, sass

I tried to use property overflow-x:scroll in css property but it does not work at all but overflow-y:scroll works in the same div. I want to use overflow for scrolling images horizontally in one specific div.
Heres my code:

html:

```
    <div class="inner-images">
        <div class="imageHolder">
            <img src="images/interior2.png">        
        </div>   
    </div>

    <div class="inner-images">
        <div class="imageHolder">
            <img src="images/house.png">        
        </div>   
    </div>

    <div class="inner-images">
        <div class="imageHolder">
            <img src="images/house.png">        
        </div>   
    </div>

    <div class="inner-images">
        <div class="imageHolder">
            <img src="images/house.png">        
        </div>   
    </div>

    <div class="inner-images">
        <div class="imageHolder">
            <img src="images/house.png">        
        </div>   
    </div>

    <div class="inner-images">
        <div class="imageHolder">
            <img src="images/house.png">        
        </div>   
    </div>

    <div class="inner-images">
        <div class="imageHolder">
            <img src="images/house.png">        
        </div>   
    </div>

    <div class="inner-images">
        <div class="imageHolder">
            <img src="images/house.png">        
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.int-images{
    height:85px;
    overflow:scroll;    
    .inner-images{
        padding:0px 32px;                                   
        .imageHolder{
            img{
                height:85px;
                width:85px;
                @include box-shadow(0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
                display:block;
                float:left;
                margin-right:15px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `white-space:nowrap` on the scrollable and `display:inline-block;` for the child elements (instead of `float:left;`). P.S: you totally don't need the extra `<div class="inner-images">` just complicates the HTML unnecessarily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
.int-images {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  .inner-images {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0px 32px;
    margin-right:15px;
    .imageHolder {
      img{
        height: 85px;
        width: 85px;
        @include box-shadow(0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLvn4psq/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    .int-images{
      overflow:scroll;  
      white-space:nowrap;

      }

    .imageHolder img{
      height:85px;
      width:85px;
      @include box-shadow(0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
      display:inline-block;
      margin-right:15px;

    }


<!-- language: lang-html -->

      <div class="int-images">
                                <div class="inner-images">
                                    <div class="imageHolder">
                                        <img src="images/interior1.png">        

                                        <img src="images/interior2.png">        

                                        <img src="images/house.png">        

                                        <img src="images/house.png">        

                                        <img src="images/house.png">        

                                        <img src="images/house.png">        

                                        <img src="images/house.png">        

                                        <img src="images/house.png">        

                                        <img src="images/house.png">        
                                    </div>   
                                </div>
                            </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```